# How can I count the number of lines in a file after a grep match?

Tags: files, grep, csv

I am trying to count the number of lines after a problematic row in a csv file. I am aware I can use the `grep -a #` syntax to output # number of lines after a match has been found. I'm only interested in the actual number of lines. I realize I could set the number to MAX_INT, pipe it into a file and do some more processing.

I'm looking for a succinct one-liner to just tell me the count.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```sh
{ grep -m1 match; grep -c ''; } <file
```

That will work w/ GNU `grep` and an `lseek()`able infile. The first `grep` will stop at 1 `-m`atch, and the second will `-c`ount every line remaining in input.

Without GNU `grep`:

```sh
{ sed '/match/q'; grep -c ''; } <file
```

Of course, w/ `grep` you can use any/all of its other options besides, and stopping at one match is not at all necessary.

Comment: Both of these also print the line, and the second on prints up to the first match and then 0 for me ?

Comment: @User112638726 - you can drop the printout of the first match with `grep -m1 match >/dev/null` of course. And your second problem is a GNU `sed` - it doesn't reset its input offset per spec. You have to use `-u` w/ GNU - which is not always desirable. I could have been clearer, but my assumption was that a GNU `grep` and GNU `sed` would come in pairs. I think, also, `grep -qm1` could work to shortcut the `/dev/null` redirect - but GNU `grep` does weird things w/ `-q` and i can't recall how those two work together.

Comment: Nice answer - really demonstrates the power of command groupings.  I don't know for sure, but I would guess `wc -l` is a little bit cheaper than `grep -c ''`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma - Yeah, i considered it *(in retrospect)*, but I'd already written it, and it almost rhymed, so I figured I'd let well enough alone. And anyway, you said it too, so I'll sleep easy now.

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way.

```
$ cat foo
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
$ awk '/^ddd/{a=FNR}END{print FNR-a}' foo
2
$
```

Comment: this is not codegolf, can you give details  ( FNR, END and so on) ?

Comment: Sure.  awk uses FNR to identify the input record number.   END is the code executed on reaching the end of the file.  So when a match is found, the current record number is recorded.  On reaching the end of the file, that number is then subtracted from the total number of lines in the file.

Comment: May aswell just use NR as it is one file.

Answer (score 6):

Another way - use of `dc` is a little esoteric, but seems to work nicely here:

```
sed -n '/problem/=;$=' prob.txt | dc -e '??r-p'
```

`sed` searches `prob.txt` for "problem" and the last line, and uses the `=` command to output the line number of both.

`dc` reads these two values onto the stack, reverses them, subracts and prints the difference.

Answer (score 5):

Entirely with sed(albeit two command with a pipe)

```
sed '/ddd/,$!d' file | sed -n '$='
```

Deletes all the line before the line and then the next command counts the lines in the new file.

Answer (score 3):

This should delete all lines up to (and including) the problemtic one and then count the remaining lines:

```
sed '1,/problem/d' data.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: (assuming "problem" is not on the first line)